# Exporting WP8 app to phone without Windows Store

Tags: windows-phone-8

It's possible to run an app on a Windows Phone 8 through Visual Studio, but can you actually save it on the phone without going through the Windows Store? It's an app only for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out myself that there is a program "Application Deployment" that comes with the SDK, which is made for exactly this!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can deploy the XAP file from Visual Studio to your phone. Just go about it as you would for debugging the project. Debug project and deploy to device. The app will stay there until you manually uninstall it.